# If $a$ and $b$ are elements of a group $G$ that satisfy the same first order formulas, is there always an automorphism of $G$ that maps $a$ to $b$?

Tags: group-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of group $G$ and assume that for any natural number $n$ and for any first-order formula $\varphi (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ with $n$ free variables in the language of groups, $G \models (\varphi (a,a, ... , a) \leftrightarrow \varphi (b,b,...,b))$

Is there always a group automorphism of $G$ that maps $a$ to $b$?

If $b$ is the image of $a$ under an automorphism of $G$, then $a$ and $b$ satisfy the same first order formulas. The question is whether the converse of that statement holds or not?

Comment: Please don't delete a question and repost. I was halfway through writing an answer, and now my draft is lost. I'll rewrite the answer tomorrow.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Shaun I respectfully disagree. The question is clear, self-contained, and well-motivated (by the last paragraph).

Comment: That's not what is meant by context here, @AlexKruckman.

Comment: @Shaun I know very well what you mean and I continue to respectfully disagree.

Comment: I'm sure there is a counterexample, even in abelian groups, but I'm finding it more difficult than I expected to produce a concrete elementary counterexample.

Answer (score 5):

An abelian counterexample appears in Theorem 6.1 in the paper "On models of the elementary theory of $(Z,+,1)$" of Mark Nadel and Jonathan Stavi.
They find a model $G$ of Th$(\mathbb Z,+)$ which has elements $g$ and $h$ satisfying the same type over $\emptyset$ such that there is no automorphism of $G$ sending $g$ to $h$.

<s>I would like to add that I do not understand the answer of Atticus Stonestrom. Given two elements $a$ and $b$ of a group $G$ satisfying the same formulas over $\emptyset$ in the language of group, it means that they realize the same type over $\emptyset$. Thus, for some elementary extension $H$ of $G$ there is an automorphism of $H$ which maps $a$ to $b$. In particular, the centralizers of $a$ and $b$ must be isomorphic...</s>

Comment: nice example!! re: my answer. it's certainly true that there is an elementary extension of $G$ in which $a$ and $b$ have isomorphic centralizers. indeed there is also an elementary substructure of $G$ in which $a$ and $b$ have isomorphic centralizer, as I point out in the answer. but that doesn't mean that $a$ and $b$ have isomorphic centralizers *in $G$*. for an easier example of this phenomenon, consider the theory $T$ of an equivalence relation $E$ which has exactly two classes, each of which is infinite. then take a model $M$ in which one class has size $\aleph_0$ and the other has size ..

Comment: ... $\aleph_1$. if $a$ is an element from the first class, and $b$ is an element from the second class, then there is an elementary extension of $M$ in which $a$ and $b$ have isomorphic equivalence classes (eg an extension in which both classes have size $\aleph_1$), but that doesn't mean that $a$ and $b$ have isomorphic equivalence classes *in $M$*. does that make sense?

Comment: @Alex Kruckman: In the paper they found a pure group counterexample to the question. In fact, they also show that it is essential to NOT have the element 1 named in order to get a non-homogeneous model...

Comment: Oh, I see. Very good!

Comment: (of course the centralizers will be elementarily equivalent in any model, but there is no reason for them to be isomorphic in a given model)

Comment: @Atticus Stonestrom: Thank you. It seems that I have to reevaluate your answer!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a counterexample with a non-abelian group. I think the question in the abelian case is quite interesting.

Given an abelian group $(U,\cdot)$, define the group $H_U$ to be the semidirect product of $U$ with a cyclic group of order $2$ that acts on $U$ by sending an element to its inverse. So, explicitly, $H_U=\{ua_U^{\varepsilon}:u\in U,\varepsilon\in\{0,1\}\}$, where $a_U$ has order $2$ and $ua_U=a_Uu^{-1}$ for all $u\in U$. Note that, if $H$ has no elements of order $2$, then the centralizer of $a_U$ in $H_U$ is just $\{1,a_U\}$.

Let $(U,\cdot),(V,\cdot)$ be torsion-free divisible abelian groups of $\mathbb{Q}$-dimensions $1$ and $2$, respectively. Define $G=H_U\times H_V$. Then $(a_U,1)$ and $(1,a_V)$ are not conjugate by an automorphism of $G$, since $(a_U,1)$ has centralizer $\{1,a_U\}\times H_V$ and $(1,a_V)$ has centralizer $H_U\times\{1,a_V\}$, and these groups are not isomorphic for dimension reasons. However, I claim that $(a_U,1)$ and $(1,a_V)$ satisfy all the same formulas in the language of groups.

There are several ways to see this, but here is one argument. Let $V_1<V$ be a $1$-dimensional subspace. Consider $H_{V_1}$ as a subgroup of $H_V$ by identifying $a_{V_1}$ with $a_V$. Then $H_U\times H_{V_1}$ is an elementary substructure of $G$. (I will write an explanation of this tomorrow as I am going to sleep now.) Moreover, there is an isomorphism $f:H_U\to H_{V_1}$ mapping $a_U$ to $a_{V}$, and now $(g,h)\mapsto (f^{-1}(h),f(g))$ gives an automorphism of $H_U\times H_{V_1}$ taking $(a_U,1)$ to $(1,a_V)$, giving the desired result.

---

Okay, so why is $H_U\times H_{V_1}$ an elementary substructure of $H_U\times H_V$? First note the following. If $(U,\cdot)$ is an abelian group with at least $2$ elements, then $(H_U,\cdot)$ is uniformly interpretable in $(U,\cdot)$: take the quotient of $U\times U$ under the equivalence relation identifying any two elements of form $(u,v)$ and $(u,w)$, where $v,w\neq 1$, let $a_U$ be the equivalence class of $(1,v)$ for some (any) $v\neq 1$, and then equip it with the usual multiplication rules for semidirect product.

If follows that, if $V_1\preccurlyeq V_2$ are abelian groups, and $V_1$ is an elementary substructure of $V_2$, then $H_{V_1}$, which is naturally a subgroup of $H_{V_2}$ by identifying $a_{V_1}$ with $a_{V_2}$, is an elementary substructure of $H_{V_2}$.

Now, in the setting of the counterexample, $V_1$ is an elementary substructure of $V$ by quantifier elimination, and so $H_{V_1}$ is an elementary substructure of $H_V$. It follows that the two-sorted structure $((H_U,\cdot),(H_{V_1},\cdot))$, which no relations between the two sorts, is an elementary substructure of $((H_U,\cdot),(H_V,\cdot))$. Since $(H_U\times H_{V_1},\cdot)$ and $(H_U\times H_V,\cdot)$ are definable by the same formula in these two structures, respectively, the claim follows.

Comment: Also, why does elementary substructurehood follow from the definability of these subgroups?

Comment: @AlexKruckman thanks re: having $U$ be abelian! and hmm, you're right, that doesn't really make sense. I was thinking that that tells you $H_U\times H_V$ is bi-interpretible with the two-sorted structure $(H_U,H_V)$ and no relations between then, and it's "clear" that $(H_U,H_{V_1})$ is an elementary substructure of $(H_U,H_V)$. but of course if you already know that $(H_U,H_{V_1})$ is an elementary substructure of $(H_U,H_V)$ then you don't need those to be interpretable in $H_U\times H_{V_1}$ and $H_U\times H_V$ to get the claim, so what I wrote doesn't make sense

Comment: I see. Maybe it's better to  note that there is a natural interpretation of $G$ (without parameters) in the two-sorted structure $(U,V)$, and since $(U,V')$ is an elementary substructure, applying the same interpretation gives an elementary substructure of $G$. And what you get is the group $H_U\times H_{V'}$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman thanks, you are right; that is an easier way to explain it! I've edited with a similar explanation